# Navigate to an Activity from a composable and removing the composable from the stack

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I know how to this when I have to navigate from one composable to another, but in case of navigating towards an Activity, I am currently using after

```
ActivityAbc.open(); navController.popBackStack()
```

But this isn't that smooth as the Activity takes sometime to create and composable gets popped up before that.